# Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[-1;1]$ such that $x^2 +f^2(x) = 1$ for all $x$. Show that $f(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ or $f(x) = -\sqrt{1-x^2}$ for all $x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, arithmetic-functions

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[-1;1]$ such that $x^2 +f^2(x) = 1$ for all $x$. Show that $f(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ or $f(x) = -\sqrt{1-x^2}$ for all $x$

---

This is my idea:
$x^2 + f^2(x) = 1 \Leftrightarrow f^2(x) = 1-x^2 $, for $x\in[-1;1] (*)$

So: With $(*)$, we can generally conclude the value of $f$ on $[-1;1]$:
$f(x) = \begin{cases} \sqrt{1-x^2} &x\in K\\ -\sqrt{1-x^2} &x\in [-1;1]\setminus K \end{cases}$
given some K satisfying $\emptyset \subseteq K \subseteq [-1;1]$ and $f$ is continuous on $[-1;1]$

(So, if $K$ contains some point $x_0$ that is not $\pm1$ then it also has to contain all points that are close to $x_0$ )

If we choose $K$ such that $K$ and $([-1;1]\setminus K$) contains at least one point that is not $\pm 1$, say respectively $c$ and $d$, we clearly have $f(c)>0>f(d)$. But since $f$ is continuous on $[c;d]$ or $[d;c]$, $\exists y\in[c;d]$ or $y\in[d;c]: f(y) = 0$, which is impossible due to the fact that $\forall x \in[c;d]$ or $[d;c]$ $\subset [-1;1]: f(x) \neq 0$. This case is not feasible.

So, we must have $K$ or ($[-1;1]\setminus K$) contains only $-1$ or $1$ or both or be empty. What if we choose $K = \text{{$1$}}$ ? By that, we still have $\text{$f$ is continuous on} [-1;1]$ and we don't seem to able to use the above argument to prove such a case is absurd.

So, shouldn't we add to hypothesis the fact that $f(-1), f(1)\neq 0$. What's wrong here ?

Comment: Both branches $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ have the same value at $-1$ and $1$, namely both branches are $0$ are both points. So you are almost done. The hypothesis won't make sense anyway, since if $x^2 + f^2(x) = 1$ then put $x =1$ and you get $f(x) = 0$, similarly $x = -1$. So $f$ is fixed at these points.

Comment: @Ak. The two functions are identical ! Thank you!

Comment: Can you use the intermediate value theroem?  Suppose there are $a,b$ not equal to $1$ so that $f(a) = \sqrt {1-a^2} > 0$ and $f(b) = -\sqrt{1-b^2}< 0$  then be intermediat value theorem there is a $c$ between them where $f(c) = 0$.  But $x^2 + 0^2 \ne 1$ unless $c=\pm 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already said in the comments, $f(-1) = f(1) = 0$ always holds. But your argument works if you apply it to
$$
 K = \{ x \in (0, 1) \mid f(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2} \} 
$$
and $(0, 1) \setminus K$.

One can also use a [*connectedness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space) argument: Use the continuity of $f$ to show that both
$$
 K = \{ x \in (0, 1) \mid f(x) > 0 \} \\
 K' = \{ x \in (0, 1) \mid f(x) < 0 \} 
$$
are open. Since $(0,1) = K \cup K'$ is connected, one of them must be empty.

The latter approach works also in the more general case where the domain of the function is a connected subset in $\Bbb R^n$ (or any topological space), when the intermediate value property can not be applied:

> Let $U \subset \Bbb R^n$ be connected and $f: U \to \Bbb R$ continuous. If $f(x) \ne 0$ for all $x \in U$ then either $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in U$ or $f(x) < 0$ for all $x \in U$.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just to proceed without appealing to the set $K$? I would proceed in this way:

Case 1. Suppose that there is a $x_0\in[-1,1]$ such that $f(x_0)\neq -\sqrt{1-x_0^2}$.

We shall prove that for all $x\in[-1,1],$ we have $ f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$. So, let $x\in [-1,1]$. If $x=-1$ or $x=1,$ then $f(x)=0=\sqrt{1-x^2}.$ Suppose now that $x \in (-1,1)$. By contradiction, assume that $f(x)=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$. We have that $f(x)<0$, since $-1<x<1$. On the other hand, $x_0$ cannot be equal to $-1$ or $1$ (otherwise, $f(x_0)=-\sqrt{1-x_0^2}=0$). Then, $-1<x_0<1$. Then, we must have $f(x_0)>0>f(x)$. Apply the continuity argument that you used before to conclude the existence of some $y\in (-1,1)$ such that $f(y)=0$. A contradiction. Then it should be $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ for all $x$.

Case 2. Suppose thay for all $x\in[-1,1]$, we have $f(x)=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$. Then we are done.

Comment: That's a good one but i'd like to simplify it a bit. Since $f^2(x) + x^2 = 1$, we must have $f(1) = f(-1)=0$. So, in case 1, we only need to consider $x_0 \in (-1;1)$ such that $f(x_0) \neq -\sqrt{1-x_0^2}$. We now need to prove $f(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ for $x\in (-1;1)\setminus \text{{$x_0$}}$ by contradiction (the case for $x=\pm1$ is proved).